# how to REGEX a url and autoadd [url] tag and fix repeat

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I need a function to auto add bbcode.

1. users use my editor type something.
2. after submit, will be run a autolink() php function.
3. if content text have url will be auto add [url] xxx [/url]

I can do it. But the bbcode editor maybe use 2 format url

A. [url]xx[/url]
B. [url=xxx] xxx[/url]

I can't fix repeat problem. here's demo code

```
$content="
http://www.google.com/logo.png

[url]http://www.yahoo.com[/url]

[url=http://yahoo.com/abc.zip]DownLoad[/url]";

$content = nl2br($content);
echo linkAdd($content);


    //auto add link
    function linkAdd($content){

        preg_match_all('~\[url=((?:ftp|https?)://.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]~s', $content, $stack);        
        foreach($stack[1] as $t) {
           $content = preg_replace('~\[url=((?:ftp|https?)://.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]~s','[url=\\1]\\2[/url]', $content,1); 
        }

        preg_match_all('~\[url](.*?)\[/url\]~s', $content, $stack);        
        foreach($stack[1] as $t) {
           $content = preg_replace('~\[url](.*?)\[/url\]~s',$t, $content,1); 
        }

        $str=preg_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_/+.~#?&//=]+)','[url]\\0[/url]',$content);           

        return $str;
    }
```

Now Results

```
[url]http://www.google.com/logo.png[/url]

[url]http://www.yahoo.com[/url]

[url=[url]http://yahoo.com/abc.zip[/url]]DownLoad[/url]
```

line one and line two is ok.

but line 3 repeat again [url]XXX[/url]

```
how to be 
[url=[url]http://yahoo.com/abc.zip[/url]]DownLoad[/url]
to
[url=http://yahoo.com/abc.zip]DownLoad[/url]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for [img] processing without protocol check :

```
<?php
$content="http://www.google.com/logo.png
[url]http://www.yahoo.com[/url]
[url=http://yahoo.com/abc.zip]DownLoad[/url]
[img]google.com/logo.png[/img]";

//$content="[img]google.com/logo.png[/img]";

//$content = nl2br($content);
echo linkAdd($content);
echo PHP_EOL;


//auto add link
function linkAdd($content)
{
    $pattern ='(
        (?:\[url\])?
        (
            (?<!url=)
            (?:f|ht)tps?://
            [-a-z0-9@:%_/+.~#?&=]+
        )
        (?:\[/url\])?
    )xi';

    $str=preg_replace($pattern,'[url]$1[/url]',$content);

    $pattern ='(
        (?:\[img\])
        ([-a-z0-9@:%_/+.~#?&=]+)
        (?:\[/img\])
    )xi';

    $str=preg_replace($pattern,'[img][url]$1[/url][/img]',$content);

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried something simpler :

```
function linkAdd($content)
{
    $pattern ='(
    (?:\[url\])?
    (
        (?<!url=)
        (?:f|ht)tps?://
        [-a-z0-9@:%_/+.~#?&=]+
    )
    (?:\[/url\])?
    )xi';

    $str=preg_replace($pattern,'[url]\\1[/url]',$content);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Wow ! so clear and simpler codes. 

I got it and Thank you so much,jmleroux!

Comment: hi,jmleroux. I want skip [img] tag, add this code "~\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]~s" after "[-a-z0-9@:%_/+.~#?&=]+"   why not work ? can you help me again?  thanks.

Comment: could you give examples of input and expected output ?

Comment: if use your code not edit. input : [img]http://www.google.com/logo.png[/img]
output will be[img][url]http://www.google.com/logo.png[/url][/img]

Comment: The function works as expected if your input is ```[img]http://google.com/logo.png[/img]```. Without protocol, it may be simpler to separate the processing of [img]. But i think you need the protocol to display the picture.

Comment: Thanks,I know. I have other function for [img]. But your code how to add a little function to skip [img].
not to be  [img][url]....?

how to set, if [img]...  not add [url]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jmleroux

this code edit form your answer,it is my mean.

thanks so so so much !

```
function linkAdd($content)
{
    $pattern ='(
        (?:\[url\])?
        (
            (?<!url=)
            (?:f|ht)tps?://
            [-a-z0-9@:%_/+.~#?&=]+
        )
        (?:\[/url\])?
    )xi';

    $str=preg_replace($pattern,'[url]$1[/url]',$content);

    $pattern ='(
        (?:\[img\])
        ([-a-z0-9@:%_/+.~#?&=]+)
        (?:\[/img\])
    )xi';

    $str=preg_replace($pattern,'[img]$1[/img]',$str);

    return $str;
}
```